# update attribute after create following condition applied to other attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

In a context of nested models and form fields, at the creation of the parent and input of a child's value (size), the goal is to apply a condition on the child's value to determine a subsequent value (product_id), all within the creation of parent action

```
class QuoteItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :quote, :inverse_of => :quote_items
  belongs_to :product

class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :quote_items, :inverse_of => :quote
```

This cannot be executed as a model method beforehand, as the model has no idea of params.
An attempt to define an after_create callback for QuoteItem

```
  after_create :set_product 
  def set_product
    @quote_item.product_id = Product.where(['min <= ? AND max >= ?', @quote_item.size, @quote_item.size]).first.select[:id]    
  end
```

does not register the product id.

A more succinct manner might be to reload the data via the controller. On action create

```
   respond_to do |format|
      if @quote_item.save
        set_product
        @quote_item.update_attribute([:quote_item][:product_id])
        format.html { redirect_to @quote_item, notice: 'Quote item was successfully created.' }
```

With identical NIL result

Comment: action done in `after_create` are not persisted

Comment: OK.  Yet working before the save and after the create command issued still is ignored:-----   def create
    bim = Product.where(['min <= ? AND max >= ?', params[:quote_item][:size], params[:quote_item][:size]]).first 
    params[:quote_item][:size] = bim
    @quote_item = QuoteItem.new(params[:quote_item])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution actually is possible in after_create.
In the nested model, update attributes after create

```
  after_create :set_product  

private

  def set_product
    product_id = Product.where(['min <= ? AND max >= ?', self.size, self.size]).first.id
    update_attributes(:product_id => product_id)
  end
```